# Debugging a haxe based ndk app on android with gdb

Tags: c++, android-ndk, gdb, haxe, gdbserver

I am trying to debug a [openfl](http://openfl.org)/[haxe](http://www.haxe.org) app on android with gdb. Since haxe/openfl compiles to c++ which is then compiled using the ndk, I am basically trying to debug an ndk app.

I got gdbserver attached to the apps process and can remote debug it using arm-linux-androideabi-gdb. But as soon as I try to get a backtrace (the app is running fine at this moment), I get this:

```
#0  0xb6e70b10 in ?? ()
#1  0xb6e4833c in ?? ()
#2  0xb6e4833c in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I understand that this can happen when I corrupted the stack by using bad pointers, but since the app is running fine (am actually looking for a runtime error, not a crash), that is not the case.